# Transforming a multivariate normal sample using the sinh-arcsinh transform

Tags: distributions, data-transformation, multivariate-normal-distribution

Let us say that we have sample from the multivariable normal distribution. I would like to understand how is possible to apply a transformation to this sample to produce sample that has the sinh-arcsinh distribution written in following paper: [Sinh-Archsinh Distributions](http://oro.open.ac.uk/22510/1/sinhasinh.pdf)

My question is related to previous question: [Transformation to increase kurtosis and skewness of normal r.v](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43482/transformation-to-increase-kurtosis-and-skewness-of-normal-r-v) , except in multivariable case. In previous question there is the inverse transform which takes normal sample and gives sinh-arcsinh sample. Is there equivalent transform to the multivariable sample?

Alternative is to take the multivariable pdf of sinh-arcsinh distribution and get the sample directly from that, but I am curious if it can be done from the multivariable normal sample.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is described in the paper quoted [Sinh-Archsinh Distributions](http://oro.open.ac.uk/22510/1/sinhasinh.pdf) and boils down to the component-by-component application of the inverse transform you mention:

1. generate $d$-dimensional Multivariate Normal variables $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,R)$, where R is a $d\times d$ correlation matrix (using e.g. method described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446093/generate-correlated-normal-random-variables)).
2. chose $d$ sets of skew and kurtosis parameters $(\epsilon_i,\delta_i)_{i=1,\cdots,d}$, with $\epsilon_i\in \mathbb{R}, \delta_i \in \mathbb{R}_0^{+}$
3. define your multivariate sin-asinh component-by component as follows : $X_{\epsilon_i,\delta_i}\equiv \sinh(\frac{\text{arcsinh}(Z_i)-\epsilon_i}{\delta_i}), \text{ for } i=1,\cdots,d$ , where $Z_i$ is the $i-$th component of your multivariate normal $Z$.